# How do I fix my definition to properly close with a return statement rather than ending with print?

Tags: python

Doing some exercises to learn Python and facing issues while closing the code properly. The idea is to get something that does this:

```
d4 = """ /\\ 
//\\\\
\\\\//
 \\/ """
print(d4)

 /\ 
//\\
\\//
 \/
```

Below is the code I have written:

```
def diamond(height):
    """Return a string resembling a diamond of specified height (measured in lines).
    height must be an even integer.
    """
    shape = ''
    lchar_top, rchar_top = '/', '\\'
    lchar_bottom, rchar_bottom = '\\' , '/'
    for i in range((height//2)):
        shape += (lchar_top * (i + 1)).rjust(height) + (rchar_top * (i + 1)).ljust(height) + '\n'
    for j in range((height//2)):
        shape += (lchar_bottom * (height//2 - j)).rjust(height) + (rchar_bottom * (height//2 - j)).ljust(height) + '\n'
    print(shape)
```

Which popped the below output

```
diamond(8)
       /\       
      //\\      
     ///\\\     
    ////\\\\    
    \\\\////    
     \\\///     
      \\//      
       \/
```

However, when I attempt to use a return statement as below:

```
def diamond(height):
    """Return a string resembling a diamond of specified height (measured in lines).
    height must be an even integer.
    """
    shape = ''
    lchar_top, rchar_top = '/', '\\'
    lchar_bottom, rchar_bottom = '\\' , '/'
    for i in range((height//2)):
        shape += (lchar_top * (i + 1)).rjust(height) + (rchar_top * (i + 1)).ljust(height) + '\n'
    for j in range((height//2)):
        shape += (lchar_bottom * (height//2 - j)).rjust(height) + (rchar_bottom * (height//2 - j)).ljust(height) + '\n'
    return shape
```

I get this output:

```
diamond(8)
Out[215]: '       /\\       \n      //\\\\      \n     ///\\\\\\     \n    ////\\\\\\\\    \n    \\\\\\\\////    \n     \\\\\\///     \n      \\\\//      \n       \\/       \n'
```

Here is the solution offered via Kaggle(sorry about the formatting issue):

```
def diamond(height):
    s = ''
    # The characters currently being used to build the left and right half of 
    # the diamond, respectively. (We need to escape the backslash with another
    # backslash so Python knows we mean a literal "\" character.)
    l, r = '/', '\\'
    # The "radius" of the diamond (used in lots of calculations)
    rad = height // 2
    for row in range(height):
        # The first time we pass the halfway mark, swap the left and right characters
        if row == rad:
            l, r = r, l
        if row < rad:
            # For the first row, use one left character and one right. For
            # the second row, use two of each, and so on...
            nchars = row+1
        else:
            # Until we go past the midpoint. Then we start counting back down to 1.
            nchars = height - row
        left = (l * nchars).rjust(rad)
        right = (r * nchars).ljust(rad)
        s += left + right + '\n'
    # Trim the last newline - we want every line to end with a newline character
    # *except* the last
    return s[:-1]
```

What do I need to change so that my attempted return statement also gives me the desired shape rather than a literal string of the appended characters and new line statements from iterating?

Comment: Please format your code properly in code blocks, this way we have to decypher everything and no one will take the time then to answer or read your question, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you use `print(diamond(8))` or it's not a solution for you?

Comment: The check methodology wants it executed via a return in the body so you you can do diamond(8) and get the correct shape on the screen. It says, "Expected [correct shape] but got [correct shape executed with print]" when attempting to use my code. The offered solution simply has a return statement with the string name yet I can't get that to work.

Comment: What is this checker("check methodology")? And what environment do you use - is it jupyter notebook?

Comment: I did not produce the problem in python2 and python3 interactive env. both works fine. looks this binds to the runtime envorment.

Comment: You can assign your function to a variable, and then print it or save it in a document. It will show correctly. The \n appear only in the console. So: shape = diamond(8) and then print(shape).

Comment: I'm running this within Spyder and it is being checked via a Kaggle notebook interface. The print solution gives the desired shape in the notebook, but it is flagged as wrong because I'm not using a return statement to close it out. I'm attempting to find a solution that will give the desired result using return. I will edit above and add the given solution that they give with a return statement.

Comment: Have you tried replacing \n for \n\r?

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrong; your function returns what it should. It's just that the shell doesn't display it properly: if it sees a 'naked' value, it prints its represenation (the same you would get using the repr() function). The print the formatted value, use print(). Compare (I'm using IDLE while you seem to be using IPython, but the principle is the same):

```
>>> "line 1\nline 2\n"
'line 1\nline 2\n'
>>> print("line 1\nline 2\n")
line 1
line 2
```

So what you have to do: instead of just calling your function, you need to call print() with the result of the function:

```
>>> print(diamond(8))
       /\       
      //\\      
     ///\\\     
    ////\\\\    
    \\\\////    
     \\\///     
      \\//      
       \/
```